# How to divide each element in list by first element

Tags: python, functional-programming

Lets consider some list:

```
arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I need to divide each element of list by its first element.
It can be done with list compehension:

```
[e / arr[0] for e in arr]
```

but I have to use some functional programming for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map`:

```
>>> arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x/arr[0],arr))
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Or as a function:

```
>>> def f(x):
    return x/arr[0]

>>> list(map(f,arr))
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>>
```

Or use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr2=np.array(arr)
>>> arr2/arr[0]
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
>>>
```

and if you want list:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr2=np.array(arr)
>>> (arr2/arr[0]).tolist()
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function `map` in combination with the class `list`:

```
arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
new_arr = list(map(lambda x: x / arr[0], arr))
```

[`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator that applies a function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

[`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) takes an iterable in order to produce a list.

Comment: Ok, this answer is a duplicate answer now

Comment: Comment removed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
out = list(map(lambda x: x/arr[0], arr))
```

And if you don't like the `lambda` expression, you can use the `truediv` (or `floordiv`) method in `operator`, but two parameters are required so here I used a little trick.

```
from operator import truediv
from itertools import starmap
arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
arr = zip(arr, [arr[0]]*len(arr))
out = list(starmap(truediv, arr))
print(out)
```

I first build a new iterable according to the question, and then use `starmap` which can `map` **multiple parameters** to a function. `truediv` in `operator` has exactly the same functionality as operator `/` but just make it run in a function way and accept two parameters and return the div result between them.

Comment: Ah you beat be in few seconds